# How can I better the readability of inline test data?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

```
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, 1, Result = 2)]
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, 2, Result = 1)]
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 2, Result = 2)]
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 2, Result = 2)]
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 10, Result = 1)]
public int TotalPageCountIsAccurate(int[] testSequence, int pageSize)
{
    var pagedList = new PagedList<int>(testSequence, 0, pageSize);
    return pagedList.TotalPageCount;
}
```

I wrote this test about five minutes ago and I can barely understand it - I dread to think how hard it will be to read in a few weeks. How can I refactor the `TestCase` attribute to improve readability?

I thought about using named arguments or (maybe) introducing a some well-named fields, but neither of these ideas appear to be feasible.

Comment: What isn't feasible about using named arguments?

Comment: The `TestCase` attribute's argument names are along the lines of `Argument1`, `Argument2` etc. which is no more descriptive than not using named arguments.

Comment: Oh right. I don't think you can make it any clearer since this is pretty much how it is done. I find it quite readable myself but you can always add some documenttion to describe what the testcases do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm right you could do at least two things:

1. Generate the array and pass only the number of items to the test method.
2. Rename `testSequence` to something more descriptive, like `items`, `elements` etc.

```
[TestCase(2, 1, Result = 2)]
[TestCase(2, 2, Result = 1)]
[TestCase(3, 2, Result = 2)]
[TestCase(4, 2, Result = 2)]
[TestCase(4, 10, Result = 1)]
public int TotalPageCountIsAccurate(int itemCount, int pageSize)
{
    // generates the item array with itemCount items
    var items = Enumerable.Range(0, itemCount).ToArray();

    var pagedList = new PagedList<int>(items, 0, pageSize);
    return pagedList.TotalPageCount;
}
```

(I can't check whether is it valid C# or not but I hope you get the idea.)

I would also create a test with an empty array.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably go with @palacsint's idea, but just to throw it out there you can also use a test case factory:

```
[TestFixture]
public class PagingTests
{
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(PagingTestCaseFactory), "TestCases")]
    public int TotalPageCountIsAccurate(int itemCount, int pageSize)
    {
        var items = Enumerable.Range(0, itemCount).ToArray();

        var pagedList = new PagedList<int>(items, 0, pageSize);

        return pagedList.TotalPageCount;
    }
}

public class PagingTestCaseFactory
{
    public static IEnumerable TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return ItemCountEqualToPageSize(2, 2).Returns(1);
            yield return ItemCountGreaterThanPageSize(2, 1).Returns(2);
            yield return ItemCountGreaterThanPageSize(3, 2).Returns(2);
            yield return ItemCountGreaterThanPageSize(4, 2).Returns(2);
            yield return ItemCountLessThanPageSize(4, 10).Returns(1);
        }
    }

    private static TestCaseData ItemCountEqualToPageSize(int itemCount, int pageSize)
    {
        return new TestCaseData(itemCount, pageSize);
    }

    private static TestCaseData ItemCountGreaterThanPageSize(int itemCount, int pageSize)
    {
        return new TestCaseData(itemCount, pageSize);
    }

    private static TestCaseData ItemCountLessThanPageSize(int itemCount, int pageSize)
    {
        return new TestCaseData(itemCount, pageSize);
    }
}
```